# Why prefer warning to error when a module does not implement a behaviour completely

Tags: elixir

From [Elixir documentation](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html):

> If a module adopting a given behaviour doesn’t implement one of the callbacks required by that behaviour, a compile-time warning will be generated.

Elixir is a very strong advocate of fail-fast approach. I'm confused about this contradiction.

Why does Elixir produce compile-time warning instead of compile-time error when one or more callbacks of a behaviour are not implemented by a module?

Comment: may be the `callback` might be less usage. The behaviour still can be achieved without this `callback` That might be the reason.

Comment: Do you mean a module can still function with partial implementation of a behaviour?

Comment: You may also ask why Erlang considers this as warning too. Looking at Erlang's popular behaviors, like `gen_server`, you may not need all of the callbacks (e.g. you don't need `handle_info`). So maybe that's the reason.

Comment: @vfsoraki I checked Erlang gen_server documentation. It provides default implementation for optional callbacks. That's why we may not need to implement all of the callbacks. My question is why give just a warning if a required callback is not implemented by a adopting module? It doesn't align with the fail fast approach.

Comment: How does it provide default implementation? I don't remember such thing. Are you not referring to Elixir? If I recall correctly, you can not provide default implementation in Erlang, but you may in Elixir. Anyway, maybe there is historical reasons behind it, and it is so expensive to change it now.

Comment: @vfsoraki Default implementation for optional callbacks is mentioned in both Erlang `gen_server` and Elixir `GenServer` documentation. For example, when we do `use GenServer`, the default implementations for optional callbacks are injected (as far as my Elixir knowledge goes).

Comment: Using the first example in http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/gen_server_concepts.html gives me warnings for undefined callbacks. Erlang does not provide default implementation (and it can not unless you go for dark magic), but Elixir can.

Comment: @vfsoraki Check the green notes in http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html

Comment: Interesting, now on Erlang 20 warnings are also gone, with the same code I mentioned.